# VirtualBox v7 download file is installing VirtualBox v6

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, security, virtualization

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I went to VirtualBox's official website and drilled down to the link to install VirtualBox 7.0.2

```
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.2/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.2-154219~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb
```

When I install this file through Ubuntu's Software Center everything appears to work fine. I then open VirtualBox, go to `About`, and the splash screen displays Virtual Box 6. Note that I have not previously installed any version of VirtualBox on this Ubuntu installation.

**Why is the VirtualBox 7 file installing VirtualBox 6?**

- Is this file compromised by some malicious actor?
- Was the wrong file linked to/uploaded to VirtualBox's site?
- Is there a default VirtualBox 6 installed on Ubuntu 22.04?
- Is the `About` splash screen wrong? Maybe somebody forgot to update it.

Comment: First point no idea second point You would need to ask the VB people Third point no Fourth point again ask the VB guys.

Comment: Thanks @David after reading your comment I should've asked a different question, has anybody successfully used the official VirtualBox 7 installation file , to install on Ubuntu 22.04. Can you try?

Comment: Please update the question to add this info.

Comment: Yes, I did it successfully. How exactly have you tried to install it? Have you opened the file with Ubuntu Software or installed via commands? If not then you installed version 6.x from the official repository.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I just downloaded the file in the link, then right click and "Open in Ubuntu Software Center", click green install button, then click open button. I did **not** do a `sudo apt install virtualbox` at any point in time. So this is just a really strange one. Not sure what happened, and it seems we may never know.